# Where's this mere with board walk and cherry blossoms in Japan?

Tags: japan, identify-this, where-on-earth

I saw this [on reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/NatureIsFuckingLit/comments/bi2go5/japan/). Please don't just fish but teach me how to fish! If you never went here, pls expound how you located.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this one too--an earlier question here? Otherwise, also likely on CNN website, although I didn't turn it up with a quick look.

Comment: I've hunted and hunted.  but the closest I can get is people saying "Cherry Blossom Lake, in Sakura, Japan" which they're not realising that sakura is just cherry blossoms.
And a couple of sites saying it's kyoto, but I can't be sure

Comment: If it were Kyoto, it should be easy to locate given how many tourists flock into Kyoto all the time …

Comment: @Jan you say that, but....well I've struggled :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The place in the photograph is actually located in Formosa Aboriginal Culture Village, in Taiwan, probably during the Sakura Festival.

> Formosa Aboriginal Culture Village was established in 1986; total area is 62 hectares. The culture village features aboriginal cultures, combining tourism, culture and educational functions. It is located in Yuchi, Nantou County, near Sun Moon Lake. The culture village has made great efforts in updating the amusement facilities and services and has shown the vigorous spirits of the aboriginal tribes.

from [eng.taiwan.net.tw](https://eng.taiwan.net.tw/m1.aspx?sNo=0002114&id=R2)

You can just look up "Formosa Aboriginal Culture Village cherry blossom/lake/Sakura" on google for more pictures.

[Another angle - you can see the rocks](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Formosan+Aboriginal+Culture+Village/@23.8653282,120.9481868,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipPqeuZYVcrvOm8ptCvJqPFpEwnla8_kvuV5727-!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipPqeuZYVcrvOm8ptCvJqPFpEwnla8_kvuV5727-%3Dw203-h152-k-no!7i3264!8i2448!4m5!3m4!1s0x3468d6f412fe1b75:0xfe11371f7e7cbb8c!8m2!3d23.8691076!4d120.9478614?hl=en)

Comment: I don't see this picture, or any picture showing this place, either on the webpage you cite, or any picture returned on images.google.com for the Formosa Aboriginal Culture Village.

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica Try searching for Formosa Aboriginal Culture Village Cherry Blossom/Lake/Sakura or something similar as the place is pretty big and there are many highlights that have been photographed.

Comment: That did it, thanks. I tried to reverse my Downvote, but the downvote is now locked. If you amend your Answer (perhaps to include the search words you suggest), I will cancel my Downvote.

Comment: Added a link to the rocks from a diff angle, definitely the same place.

Comment: Downvote removed.